# vertexPipelineStoresAndAtomics warning for Vulkan SSBO vertex shader

Tags: glsl, vulkan, spir-v

I want to use an array of `vec3` in my Vertex shader. I created

```
layout(binding = 1) readonly buffer MyBuffer {
   vec3 buf[];
} myBuffer;
...
vec test = myBuffer[gl_VertexIndex];
```

layout in my GLSL and `glslc` it over to my SPIR-V where it has it's `NonWriteable` op-code. I did all the CPU side work setting it up with a descriptor set and all. It seems that the data is getting through correctly, but I get this warning through the validation layer

```
ERROR: [Validation] Code 15 : Object: VK_NULL_HANDLE (Type = 0) | Shader requires vertexPipelineStoresAndAtomics but is not enabled on the device
```

Which then looking more into it, I realize the `vertexPipelineStoresAndAtomics` is just for non-compute shaders to write to, but I am only ever reading the data so not sure why it is yelling at me. Also it seems like it is still working so is this a false negative error or am I doing something completely wrong?

Comment: From the spec: "vertexPipelineStoresAndAtomics [...] If this feature is not enabled, all storage image, storage texel buffers, and storage buffer variables used by these stages in shader modules must be decorated with the NonWriteable decoration (or the readonly memory qualifier in GLSL)." You provide `readonly` qualifier, so if You also set everything else correctly, than this is probably a bug in validation layers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently an actively tracked bug in the validation suite. See https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers/issues/2526 for more information.